# Никак не подключаются js файл к Bootstrap карусели

Tags: javascript, html, django

Никак не могу подключить js файлы к PythonDjango странице.

Главное css файлы хорошо работают, а js вообще никак. Карусель попросту не двигается, а стрелки вообще говорят, что это ссылка на страницу и переходят на верх.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load static %}

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'boar/css/index.css' %}">
    <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'boar/css/style-stock-content.css' %}">
    <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'boar/css/style-about-content.css' %}">
    <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'boar/css/style-news-content.css' %}">

    <title>{% block title %}Склад{% endblock %}</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'boar/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'boar/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'boar/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'boar/js/pooper.min.js' %}"></script>




    <style>
       
        .col-center {
            margin: 0 auto;
            float: none !important;
        }
        .carousel {
            padding: 0 70px;
        }
        .carousel .carousel-item {
            color: #999;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 3123px;
    width: 1260px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 290px;
        }
        .carousel .carousel-item .img-box {
            width: 135px;
            height: 135px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        .carousel .img-box img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
        .carousel .testimonial {
            padding: 30px 0 10px;
        }
        .carousel .overview {   
            font-style: italic;
        }
        .carousel .overview b {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #7AA641;
        }
        .carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next {
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            margin-top: -20px;
            top: 50%;
            background: none;
        }
        .carousel-control-prev i, .carousel-control-next i {
            font-size: 68px;
            line-height: 42px;
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
            text-shadow: 0 3px 3px #e6e6e6, 0 0 0 #000;
        }
       
        </style>
</head>

<body>
     <!-- Шапка -->
<header>
    <div class = "header-background"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/header-background.png' %}"/></div>
    <a href = "{% url 'home' %}"><div class = "menu-home">Главная</div></a>
    <a href = "{% url 'stock' %}"><div class = "menu-stock">Склад</div></a>
    <a href = "{% url 'about' %}"><div class = "menu-about">О нас</div></a>
    <a href = "{% url 'news' %}"><div class = "menu-news">Новости</div></a>
    <div class = "logo"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/Logo.png' %}"/></div>

    <div class = "insta"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/Insta.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "twit"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/twit.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "vk"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/vk.png' %}"/></div>

    <div class = "ikon-phone"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/ikon-phone.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "ikon-maps"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/maps-ikon.png' %}"/></div>

    <div class = "WhatTele">WhatsApp|Telegram</div>
    <div class = "number">+8(000)000-00-00</div>

    <div class = "address">Адрес</div>
    <div class = "add">Россия, г.Москва, ул. Кирова, д 16</div>
</header>

{% block content %}

        <div class="container-xl">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                       
                        <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <div class = "slide_one">
                                    <div class = "stock-product-1"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product1.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-1-text">Мясо кролика Мкк Балтийский в собственном соку 325 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva1"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price1">325 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-2"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product2.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-2-text">Говядина Главпродукт тушеная экстра 525 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva2"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price2">240 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-3"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product3.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-3-text">Цыпленок тушеный Батькин резерв филе в собственном соку 338 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva3"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price3">320 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-4"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product4.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-4-text">Свинина тушеная Семейный запас 525 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva4"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price4">200 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-5"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product5.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-5-text">Говядина тушеная Батькин резерв 338 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva5"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price5">425 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-6"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product6.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-6-text">Тушенка Aro кусковая свинина 340 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva6"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price6">525 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-7"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product7.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-7-text">Говядина тушеная БКК Золото Байкала тушеная ГОСТ в собственном соку 338 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva7"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price7">325 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-8"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product8.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-8-text">Свинина Мясной Союз тушеная кусковая 340 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva8"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price8">150 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-9"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product9.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-9-text">Свинина тушеная Таврия ГОСТ 338 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva9"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price9">325 руб</div>
                                    </div>
                            
                            
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <div class = "slide_one">
                                    <div class = "stock-product-1"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product1.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-1-text">Мясо кролика Мкк Балтийский в собственном соку 325 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva1"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price1">325 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-2"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product2.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-2-text">Говядина Главпродукт тушеная экстра 525 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva2"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price2">240 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-3"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product3.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-3-text">Цыпленок тушеный Батькин резерв филе в собственном соку 338 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva3"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price3">320 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-4"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product4.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-4-text">Свинина тушеная Семейный запас 525 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva4"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price4">200 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-5"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product5.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-5-text">Говядина тушеная Батькин резерв 338 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva5"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price5">425 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-6"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product6.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-6-text">Тушенка Aro кусковая свинина 340 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva6"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price6">525 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-7"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product7.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-7-text">Говядина тушеная БКК Золото Байкала тушеная ГОСТ в собственном соку 338 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva7"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price7">325 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-8"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product8.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-8-text">Свинина Мясной Союз тушеная кусковая 340 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva8"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price8">150 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-9"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product9.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-9-text">Свинина тушеная Таврия ГОСТ 338 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva9"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price9">325 руб</div>
                                    </div>
                            
                            
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <div class = "slide_one">
                                    <div class = "stock-product-1"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product1.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-1-text">Мясо кролика Мкк Балтийский в собственном соку 325 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva1"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price1">325 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-2"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product2.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-2-text">Говядина Главпродукт тушеная экстра 525 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva2"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price2">240 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-3"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product3.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-3-text">Цыпленок тушеный Батькин резерв филе в собственном соку 338 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva3"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price3">320 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-4"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product4.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-4-text">Свинина тушеная Семейный запас 525 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva4"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price4">200 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-5"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product5.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-5-text">Говядина тушеная Батькин резерв 338 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva5"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price5">425 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-6"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product6.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-6-text">Тушенка Aro кусковая свинина 340 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva6"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price6">525 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-7"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product7.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-7-text">Говядина тушеная БКК Золото Байкала тушеная ГОСТ в собственном соку 338 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva7"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price7">325 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-8"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product8.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-8-text">Свинина Мясной Союз тушеная кусковая 340 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva8"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price8">150 руб</div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class = "stock-product-9"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/product9.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "stock-product-9-text">Свинина тушеная Таврия ГОСТ 338 г</div>
                                    <div class = "canva9"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/canva.png' %}"/></div>
                                    <div class = "price9">325 руб</div>
                                    </div>
                            
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Carousel controls -->
                        <div class="control-qa">
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" id="button-left_question_answer" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" id="button-right_question_answer" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                            </a>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endblock content %}
 <!-- Подвал -->
 <footer>
    <div class = "footer-background"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/footer-background.png' %}"/></div>

    <div class = "inst-footer"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/insta-footer.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "twit-footer"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/twit-footer.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "vk-footer"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/vk-footer.png' %}"/></div>

    <div class = "ikon-maps-footer"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/maps-ikon-footer.png' %}"/></div>
    <div class = "ikon-phone-footer"><img src = "{% static 'boar/image/ikon-phone-footer.png' %}"/></div>

    <div class = "WhatTele-footer">WhatsApp|Telegram</div>
    <div class = "number-footer">+8(000)000-00-00</div>

    <div class = "address-footer">Адрес</div>
    <div class = "add-footer">Россия, г.Москва, ул. Кирова, д 16</div>
</footer>


</body>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

settings.py

```js
"""
Django settings for ShopBoar project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-0l_awyr8&ftgoddwmytwhg09iou2norfz(a_0zb^o*s3xh&^ei'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ShopBoar.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'boar/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ShopBoar.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "boar/static"),
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Comment: Ошибки в консоли смотрели?

Comment: Все. Я уже решила. Там js подключается через http://